Select the first row of each GROUP BY in SQL Server
I have two tables and 3 joined columns, ORDER_NO, REASON and ROWID. ORDER_NO is not unique, and I am trying to get the most recent Reason for each order by selecting the max ROWID number by order.
Table after join
Expected result
I used DISTINCT because I couldn't think about a GROUP BY, but anyone is fine.
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (CAST(oh.ORDER_NO AS INTEGER)) AS 'ORDER_NO',
    r.DESCR AS 'REASON',
    CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) AS 'ROWID'
FROM
    ORD_HOLD oh
INNER JOIN
    REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD
ORDER BY
    CAST(oh.ORDER_NO AS INTEGER), CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC

I also tried something after reading this, but didn't work too: Get top 1 row of each group
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.ORDER_NO ORDER BY CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ORD_HOLD oh
    INNER JOIN
        REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD
)
SELECT *
FROM cte

Error:

Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The column 'REASON_CD' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Asked over 500 times? Also, please don't post screenshots of data, code, or errors.

Your second try is the way to go, but read the error message, when you do: select * you fetch columns from both tables and there are duplicate column names, and sql doesn't like that. Just fetch the distinct columns you're looking for and then change the end to select * from cte where rn = 1

duplicate of: The column was specified multiple times (which you could have found when doing research)

Row Number() is an older but viable design pattern. Look at table value functions for Cross Apply or outer apply for SQL server for the current design pattern.  Example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7623/return-top-rows-in-sql-using-apply-row-number-functions/

@xQbert row_number() still tends to be faster and use fewer reads. But.... that's an implementation detail, meaning MS may one day find a way to optimize APPLY to gain parity or even improve on the window function. Also, I still personally find APPLY easier to write and reason about, especially because you can use it multiple times in the same complex query to pull in a top value from different logical areas, which can be more challenging with a windowing function. But, for the moment at least, the windowing functions are definitely more efficient.

@JoelCoehoorn  Good to know I've not had to deal with a large enough dataset I guess.  I too appreciate the readability of the apply; and it is the "newer" design pattern; not saying the other methods don't work; just newer.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thank you all for your comments (and understood about images). I will take a look at APPLY too.

Start with just the inner query:
SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.ORDER_NO ORDER BY CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC) AS rn
FROM
    ORD_HOLD oh
INNER JOIN
    REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD

This much is legal, even though both the ORD_HOLD and REASON tables provide a REASON_CD column, because at this point you can still know which column is which, ie you can reference either oh.REASON_CD or r.REASON_CD to distinguish them.
Note that while the SQL may work at this point, the duplicate names can still sometimes confuse client code and reporting tools and libraries, so it's still something to be aware of and avoid when possible.
Additionally, if this is all you want to do, you don't have to wrap it in a CTE at all; you'll get the results you want. However, we know you'll want to use this CTE as part of something more complicated than SELECT * FROM cte, ie add a WHERE rn=1 filter. Future versions of SQL Server will also likely let you avoid the CTE using a QUALIFY clause, but for now on-premise SQL Server still needs this.
So let's move to the next level, with the full query:
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.ORDER_NO ORDER BY CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ORD_HOLD oh
    INNER JOIN
        REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD
)
SELECT *
FROM cte

The thing to understand here is once you nest the inner query as a subquery, whether as a CTE or anything else, the original source tables and alias names no longer apply. At all. There is no more oh.REASON_CD or r.REASON_CD, it's just cte.REASON_CD.
This means we have a problem, because that REASON_CD expression is ambiguous, with no way at all to declare which one you want. It means the query is no longer legal, because you have two columns with the same name (REASON_CD) in the same set, under the same object identifier. This is not allowed, and the fact you previously filtered them to have the same value does not matter.
The solution to this is to specify your columns instead of using the * placeholder, which has always been  the correct thing to do.

As per my understanding of your problem your query should look something like:
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        oh.ORDER_NO,
        oh.ROWID,
        r.REASON_CD,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.ORDER_NO ORDER BY CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ORD_HOLD oh
    INNER JOIN
        REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
where rn = 1;

The error you specified is because you are selecting all columns from both the tables due to the JOIN. you need to select only specific columns and if you want to fetch REASON Column from both tables in that case you need to mention column aliases see example below:
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        oh.ORDER_NO,
        oh.ROWID,
        oh.REASON_CD as a,
        r.REASON_CD as b,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.ORDER_NO ORDER BY CAST(oh.ROWID AS INTEGER) DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ORD_HOLD oh
    INNER JOIN
        REASON r ON oh.REASON_CD = r.REASON_CD
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
where rn = 1;

